# Using Python client lib decorator in subscription callback

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've been building a small service with the Mirror API on GAE using the decorators from the Google APIs Client Library for Python to automate the OAuth dance. I've been having some problems getting the notification handler for subscriptions to work, and I just realized that by removing the decorator from the POST method that processes the subscription ping, it works (which is to say I can enter the method and inspect the JSON body).

This makes total sense, since the Mirror API is calling the callback, not a user.

But I've still got to make an authorized request to handle the payload, which means I'll need to an authorized service object, so do I need to manually write the OAuth for this part, or will the library automatically get the credentials for the user that invoked the notification?

Thanks for your help!

```
 # leaving the decorator on the method causes it not to work
 # @decorator.oauth_required
 def post(self):

    logging.info('PAYLOAD %s' % self.request.body)

    # get the authorized object created by the decorator
    # this isn't going to work since it's dependent on the decorator
    http = decorator.http()

    # handle the inbound JSON payload from the body of the request via POST
    data = json.load(self.request.body)
    item_id = data["itemId"]
    user_id  = data["userToken"]
    update_item = mirror_api_service.timeline().get(id=item_id).execute(http=http)

    for user_action in data.get('userActions',[]):
        if user_action.get('type') == 'LAUNCH':

            speakable_text = "Echoing your speech input: " % update_item["text"]

            card_content = {
                "text": speakable_text,
                "speakableText": speakable_text,
                "notification": { "level": "DEFAULT" }
            }

            try:
                mirror_api_service.timeline().insert(body=card_content).execute(http=http)      
                self.response.set_status(200)
            except errors.HttpError, error:
                logging.warn('PROBLEM: ' + str(error))  

            # only process the first userAction
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load your credential and use it to create an API client. Here's a code snippet from the [Python quick start](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/notify/handler.py#L43).

```
  def post(self):
    """Handles notification pings."""
    logging.info('Got a notification with payload %s', self.request.body)
    data = json.loads(self.request.body)
    userid = data['userToken']

    self.mirror_service = util.create_service(
        'mirror', 'v1',
        StorageByKeyName(Credentials, userid, 'credentials').get())

    if data.get('collection') == 'locations':
      self._handle_locations_notification(data)
    elif data.get('collection') == 'timeline':
      self._handle_timeline_notification(data)
```

Comment: Got it...as I suspected. I was going to copy the docs, but I didn't know if the client lib would do it on its own. Thanks, Jenny!